# Eclipse IDE doesn't copy paste the complete Hex String

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

This is the hex string that I need to use for my JAVA program-

```
000A000346503600013600066D6F62696C650003313031000570686F746F0C064646443846464530303031303441343634393436303030313032303030303031303030313030303046464442303034333030353033373343343633433332353034363431343635413535353035463738433838323738364536453738463541464239393143384646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464442303034333031353535413541373836393738454238323832454246464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464330303031313038303036323030354630333031323230303032313130313033313130314646433430303146303030303031303530313031303130313031303130303030303030303030303030303030303130323033303430353036303730383039304130424646433430304235313030303032303130333033303230343033303530353034303430303030303137443031303230333030303431313035313232313331343130363133353136313037323237313134333238313931413130383233343242314331313535324431463032343333363237323832303930413136313731383139314132353236323732383239324133343335333633373338333933413433343434353436343734383439344135333534353535363537353835393541363336343635363636373638363936413733373437353736373737383739374138333834383538363837383838393841393239333934393539363937393839393941413241334134413541364137413841394141423242334234423542364237423842394241433243334334433543364337433843394341443244334434443544364437443844394441453145324533453445354536453745384539454146314632463346344635463646374638463946414646433430303146303130303033303130313031303130313031303130313031303030303030303030303030303130323033303430353036303730383039304130424646433430304235313130303032303130323034303430333034303730353034303430303031303237373030303130323033313130343035323133313036313234313531303736313731313332323332383130383134343239314131423143313039323333333532463031353632373244313041313632343334453132354631313731383139314132363237323832393241333533363337333833393341343334343435343634373438343934413533353435353536353735383539354136333634363536363637363836393641373337343735373637373738373937413832383338343835383638373838383938413932393339343935393639373938393939414132413341344135413641374138413941414232423342344235423642374238423942414332433343344335433643374338433943414432443344344435443644374438443944414532453345344535453645374538453945414632463346344635463646374638463946414646444130303043303330313030303231313033313130303346303036454533444139313946314345373945443444323437374136463037443641324332313442393234464135314246384330413644334230343030343530303236454346364536393534364545373231364134394130303838313833314339454336383830303639333043333343373441373630314238314337333933343946384633343446423433393242433143463431353145344431363032343033334430443238303534463334443530354241373032394646433543384530374244323030323341443041344634413033373343384135304139394344323032333343443238303430454443443339393338303733463441373643303032463633454444453842383130453338333532323242424530323932374641353237393444394336333030463741423841303437314544354541324138303437383434383431364345303734313439383438464137303744364134343630353437334345324142434446373844333433313836313539314339444638464333333431423446343743464531344343393037333532433645464234393030373144413942313043393033323730343630374138413846373631373135363833383735323346333135353635354441373845383641364330333439433945333843353338333743413437414433333138413531343538304232454238303032463234373441363332423043313237444330413942424536414233333145353739433636413130313636333643384338314330413731323036443145424445413238394231303132334144333433333036353536334437463441423435323434453045303043373541384442394541343637464346453535323246344531414131303737343938373033314436383042304436354338314542443331344141453431313946344335334237313639333138453934443930303237364138333941373731313136373633453435343932304338323333393134433643303138323333384546344536364639424630313432313130453344323934374432413538453232344534463441373138443330333138333845463441453033433943463139433533314330324245464441383234373630364133323146414534314139343830373330363538443535353839434534453030464633463935303043383838344230314238313138433841393943324639343830463338453639333732393030364535314446303241414535313041344232373146333630314533323137333431363234373546393937424435393131384345463533383237393234314542353134413135343936353339413630323434433142374631444638453238324143384642383143453638423545353142444344344135373345463445433439353842363436303845373339413443453445344432314530393134463839343331453739453241373630314541454442373033393233394134444137384346333532324138353345423433304138423831313336343943453731344432413445303645323732363943433436333134383943424138314542353438303544434631453535343032313439313933344330313934303635464243333945413038464341394442393434443232423933423442353344313233434631443345423535423134383435423844423930434134314634413842453636444335423844444542353631443935343735413839363337393845374132464144303043393644343644383431463733394139343735434533384634413643334632413238303741353139433438423831434634413634393545343546444631354635453935324141453036313446313444424146424341433345393439313943384530453342443434383039383043373533343136303046424433303338433831464345393138463339454235313630323338453337363443453046453534463836333635373142393438414235313746414135464136363942323635374536303731354138434134353737434143374236344432313432424634463541394436303342374536454643443438413834304546344145333242433531303633463331433846344142324334323237314330303239343238444330453037354634413733433631433742443142383131323143364431393339303339464341383933323038334538373841353233313235333234334342363344384631353634384539433645383846413845364141414236333146354142364137373239434634453935353345453338434633454434393831333844413030453444324537423031353045464339453943353344373044454243353636443038423931464641423546413041353230313034313139313435313536353038444442454234423435313430303837414432463633343531343230323145453345423443374541444634333435313534323132324541374539353035433030323633383138413238413443303037444531463441303735333435313532433437464644390003465035000135000346503400013400034650330001330005666E616D650001410003465032000132000346503100013100056C6E616D65000142
```

The above string corresponds to a few values of a Hashtable.
That is, the hashtable contains key value pairs like {Sex=Male, Name=aaa, Blood Group=B+, photo=(/*the string value of an image*/). The hashtable values, on encoding to a hex string give the above mentioned hex string.
However, the image string is not displayed.

It's not that it doesn't print or gives an error or reads null. It just shows blank spaces throughout the length of the image string.

And it's not just on running the code. I tried it on a different system and it worked perfectly. So, I used it to obtain the string value. But when I tried to copy paste it in my IDE, I kid you not, this is what was being pasted.

```
000A000346503600013600066D6F62696C650003313031000570686F746F0C (/*Blank spaces equal to the length of the missing data*/)  E616D65000142
```

And when I copied this string which has the blanks, and pasted it on a text editor, it showed the complete string again. I'm not even kidding.

This is really weird and frustrating. Can anyone figure out why?

I'm using ADT Build: v22.6.2-1085508.

Comment: Did you try pasting it in parts?

Comment: @CeilingGecko. Yes, pasting it in parts doesn't work either.

Comment: @AaronDigulla that would be my last resort. I think I'll wait to see if any other solution comes up.

Comment: @Deathstroke: That's not a bug of the IDE. Something is really broken on your computer. Try in this order: Restart eclipse, reboot, test your memory, reinstall, new computer.